# Salt - multiple requirement files to virtualenv

Tags: django, virtualenv, pip, salt-stack

I would like to manage my Django project with Salt (http://saltstack.com). In my states I have

```
/srv/MyProject/venv:
    virtualenv.managed:
        - no_site_packages: True
        - runas: myproject
        - requirements: /srv/MyProject/src/requirements.txt
        - require:
            - user: myproject
```

And in requirements.txt I load other files (production.txt, local.txt...):

```
-r requirements/production.txt
```

When I run salt, it fails:

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/requirements/production.txt'
```

How can I change path from `/tmp/` to `/srv/MyProject/src/`? I tried to use `cwd` option, but it is the same.

Comment: What version of salt do you use?

Comment: Does the requirements.txt work with a manual virtualenv?  I don't think salt ever looks in requirements.txt, it just makes sure it's available for pip to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an easier way, set no_chown: True on the virtualenv and it works.  See this issue for more info:

https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/4832

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was in salt roots to add a requirements.txt that had:

```
-r /srv/MyProject/src/requirements.txt
```

then in the state, link to it via salt like so:

```
- requirements: salt://requirements.txt
```

This then allows you to include further requirements as normal without issues.